# JavaScript RegExp help for BBCode

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this RegExp expression I found couple weeks ago

```
/([\r\n])|(?:\[([a-z\*]{1,16})(?:=([^\x00-\x1F"'\(\)<>\[\]]{1,256}))?\])|(?:\[\/([a-z]{1,16})\])/ig
```

And it's working to find the BBCode tags such as `[url]` and `[code]`.

However if I try `[url="http://www.google.com"]` it won't match. I'm not very good at RegExp and I can't figure out how to still be valid but the `="http://www.google.com"` be optional.

This also fails for `[color="red"]` but figure it is the same issue the url tag is having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part: `[^\x00-\x1F"'\(\)<>\[\]]` says that after the `=`there must not be a ". That means your regexp matches `[url=http://stackoverflow.com]`. If you want to have quotes you can simply put them around your capturing group:

```
/([\r\n])|(?:\[([a-z\*]{1,16})(?:="([^\x00-\x1F"'\(\)<>\[\]]{1,256})")?\])|(?:\[\/([a-z]{1,16})\])/gi
```

Comment: That worked but now without the option doesn't work... like [url] doesn't

Comment: /([\r\n])|(?:\[([a-z\*]{1,16})(?:=([^\x00-\x1F'\(\)<>\[\]]{1,256}))?\])|(?:\[\/([a-z]{1,16})\])/ig

Comment: placed the second " wrong. now it should work and match [url], [url="sfdgs"] and [/url]

Answer (score 1):

I think you would benefit from explicitly enumerating all the tags you want to match, since it should allow matching the closing tag more specifically.

Here's a [sample code](http://jsfiddle.net/7wENA/):

```
var tags = [ 'url', 'code', 'b' ]; // add more tags

var regParts = tags.map(function (tag) {
    return '(\\[' + tag + '(?:="[^"]*")?\\](?=.*?\\[\\/' + tag + '\\]))';
});

var re = new RegExp(regParts.join('|'), 'g');
```

You might notice that the regular expression is composed from a set of smaller ones, each representing a single tag with a possible attribute (`(?:="[^"]*")?`, see explanation below) of variable length, like `[url="google.com"]`, and separated with the alternation operator `|`.

`(="[^"]*")?` means an `=` symbol, then a double quote, followed by any symbol other than double quote (`[^"]`) in any quantity, i.e. 0 or more, (`*`), followed by a closing quote. The final `?` means that the whole group may not be present at all.